# Bidirectional communication between Arduino and Raspberry Pi over USB possible?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, usb, python, raspberrypi

Is it possible to have bidirectional communication betweeen an Arduino Uno Rev 3 and a Raspberry Pi Modell B+ running Rasbian? They're connected ofer USB, and it would be good if I could use Python on the Pi.

Comment: Other than with the normal serial object?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can you explain what you mean? Sorry I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The Arduino Uno implements a serial protocol inside the USB signal using hardware.  This is how it is built.  The Linux side is a bit more complex as there are many USB protocols.  Here is a [howto](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/LinuxTTY) which talks about the Linux side of the Arduino / Linux connection.

To be clear, Rasbian is a derivative of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a USB serial communication between a raspberry pi and an Arduino. And it is  much more easier when using Python on the raspberry pi.

Python has a serial library within it's standard library which you can import on the raspberry pi and then use it to send or receive data to/from the Arduino or the raspberry pi.(Just connected via USB cable).

[Here is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Pde26llc7s) for a very similar requirement on YouTube.